# Is it possible to impose periodic boundary conditions on Chebyshev differentiation matrix?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, periodic-functions, chebyshev-polynomials

I have been using the Chebyshev collocation method for solving PDEs. In particular to solve a 3D generalized Poisson's equation. One of the problems I am facing is that one of my dimensions is periodic and would require periodic BCs. I have been following with the Trefethen's book "Spectral Methods in Matlab", but so far do not see anything like that. I am wondering if it's not possible even though we can apply FFTs to these derivative matrices to speed up things. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Yes it is possible, though it is not optimal 2) If you want a ready made code that can solve your problem relatively easily, I suggest you look at the [Dedalus project](https://dedalus-project.org/). Also, your question is better off asked on the [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hey! Thanks. My problem is originally I had a 2D spectral methods using Fourier basis to solve for my generalized Poisson's equation. However, now that I am extending it in 3D and the third dimension is not required. I thought would be better to rewrite the whole potential solver using Chebyshev. I will look into this project. Thanks again.

Comment: I am wondering if Dedalus project uses only MHD equations to solve for this.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment doesn't make sense to me in the context of our conversation. What do the MHD (magnetohydrodynamic) equations have to do with anything?

Comment: Oh sorry I got confused. I checked the website and it seems they solve fluid equations which is great. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: They solve _arbitrary_ systems of equations, and you can couple Fourier and Chebyshev bases together. The developers all work in fluid dynamics which is why you'll see those kinds of examples given in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the examples. I would like to see a way (example) where I can easily couple the Chebyshev basis in my 2D Fourier basis code. That would solve my issue.